# Can't access unique identifier for Bixby using code from docs

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

To access a unique identifier for Bixby, I'm trying to access the `contactId` field within the `contact` library (which is also `viv.self` I think?). I tried using the code snippet found in the docs [here](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.self#passing-self-to-your-action), but I'm getting some errors.

### Code Snippet ([Source](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.self#passing-self-to-your-action))

```
text (Name) {
  extends (contact.StructuredName)
}
```

### Errors

**ERROR: invalid capsule alias contact**

**ERROR: unknown super-type: contact.contactId**

---

I would ultimately like to do something like this

```
integer (Identifier) {
  extends (contact.ContactId)
}
```

Would appreciate any help on accessing this data!

Comment: This might be a super basic question but: Have you imported the viv.contact library capsule into your capsule by adding it to your `capsule-imports`?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up finding another way to get a device identifier from these [docs](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.js-actions#passing-user-context-information). There's also a sample capsule [here](https://github.com/bixbydevelopers/capsule-samples-collection/tree/master/user-context).

---

> In your corresponding JavaScript file, access the $vivContext.locale parameter to return the locale information.

```
module.exports.function = function accessVivContext (dummyInput, $vivContext) {
  var result = "Testing Access vivContext..."

  // See docs for all the properties of $vivContext
  result = $vivContext.userId
  return result 
}
```

> You would then need to configure your endpoints for this action like below, including making sure that you set up the proper accepted-inputs for your endpoint:

```
action-endpoint (AccessVivContext) {
  accepted-inputs (dummyInput, $vivContext) 
  local-endpoint ("AccessVivContext.js")
}
```